# Python 3.5 Attribute Error - requests

Tags: attributes, python-requests

I am new to programming and trying to teach myself Python using online tutorials. I am using PyCharm to code.
I am trying to use the requests module to get a website.
To test requests was working, I entered:

> import requests
>
> requests.get('http:\google.com')

Yet I received an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Avraham Tzion/PycharmProjects/untitled/Spider.py", line 16, in
>
> ```
>    requests.get('http://google.com')
> ```
>
> AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

The requests I have installed is the newest version, 2.9.1.
How can I run the 'get' function? I can't figure out why it isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying your example, it worked for me.

```
import requests
>>> requests.get('http://google.com')
<Response [200]>
```

1. created new, clean virtualenv
2. pip install requests # which downloaded version 2.9.1)
3. opened python interpreter
4. tried the following example

Comment: Not sure what it was, but just starting a new, clean virtualenv did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: שמחתי לעזור! (translated: i am glad to help)

Answer (score 0):

Isnt request an extermal module?
Have you tried
pip install requests

Comment: Requests is installed. It also appears on the list of project interpreters.